# Parameter substitution within shell script when executing another command

Tags: shell, curl

I have written a script which curls and downloads a DB

`DB_URL="$(curl --user $1:$2 -s https://myurl.com/ | grep -o \http\:[a-zA-Z.0-9\:/-]* | grep DBNAME$ | tail -1)"`

echo -e "\033[33;31m The database is here :"
echo $DB_URL

But, the $1 and $2 are not being substituted with the two params that I am passing. How do I do it? I have tried many different ways to substitute but still no success.

Works fine when executed directly by replacing $1 and $2 with correct username and password

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this worked :

`DB_URL=$(curl --user "$1":"$2" -s https://myurl.com/ | grep -o \http\:[a-zA-Z.0-9\:/-]* | grep DBNAME$ | tail -1)`

Had to put the variables in quotes.

See glenn's comment below. The quotes prevented special characters in the password from being interpreted.

Comment: This is not the case. Try e.g. `var=foo; echo "$var" $var`.

Comment: @thatotherguy, but try `var="foo bar"; printf "%s\n" "$var" $var` -- jumpa's answer is correct

Comment: @jumpa, you should put the pattern in single quotes: `grep -o 'http://[[:alnum:].:/-]*'` -- also `h` and `:` are not special to the shell and don't need to be escaped, but `[`, `]` and `*` **are** special (filename pattern expansion) so should be escaped or quoted.

Comment: The difference between quotes and no quotes: after expansion, no quotes are subject to word splitting and filename expansion. Quotes protect that. The `--user` option is expecting a single word for an argument: I'm guessing that the username or password had a space, or an asterisk that was expanding into a list of filenames.

Comment: Thanks all. @glennjackman there were special characters in the password. Now that I think about it, the original issue must have been the special characters !! Thanks man.